# Making a bot join a vc and play music

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My code makes the bot join the vc, but it doesn't play music, also the bot gives the following error, i don't understand it and i really need help fixing the error :(

```
Ignoring exception in command play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\cool boi\coolboi.py", line 184, in play
    vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 3209, in join_voice_channel
    voice = VoiceClient(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 217, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice")
RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

and the code is

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
    url = ctx.message.content
    url = url.strip(' play ')

    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

Comment: probably you should install PyNaCl. So far in your question about discord bot - install requested a library, to (look for a name in the last line of a traceback)

Answer (score 3):

```
PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

You need to install the PyNaCl library in order to use the voice features.  Run

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
```

to install it.

Comment: well there is green around him but he doesn't make sound but that is probably my fault XD

Comment: If you just `pip install discord.py` it won't install PyNaCl, (because it's a big dependency). run the above command to install the voice-specific dependencies (on some systems this command will just be `pip install -U discord.py[voice]`, you may have to play with it a little.

Comment: With Zsh (default on macOS), you may have to use quotes because of the `[`. Use it like this, it is platform-independent: `python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"`