# RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

Tags: python, discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pradeep Tejwani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Pradeep Tejwani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pradeep Tejwani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

This is my error even though I have both the python libraries `pynacl` and `discord.py[voice]` installed. I tried it so many times but still got same error. I have even updated my library to newer versions but nothing changed.

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}")

#leave cmd
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        print(f"The bot has left {channel}")
        await ctx.send(f"Left {channel}")
    else:
        print("Bot was told to leave voice channel, but was not in one")
        await ctx.send("Don't think I am in a voice channel")
```

Comment: are you sure you are running your script with the same interpreter you used to install the packages using pip?

Comment: I used vs code (virtual studio code) to run the script and cmd prompt to install the packages

Comment: run the command `where python` from both of the terminals (CMD and VScode) and make sure they point to the same place

Comment: i get nothing when i run where python in vs code

Comment: ok wait i have same result in cmd and vs code

Comment: when i did where python

Comment: @Mogi ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: did you `import` the needed libraries..? because I don't see it in the code you pasted. If you did, can you import it in an interactive python session?

Comment: wdym interactive python session?

Comment: ```import youtube_db``` i just imported this

Comment: youtube_dl eee*

Comment: try installing `libsodium-dev`
https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot/issues/841

Comment: or follow this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936196/making-a-bot-join-a-vc-and-play-music

Answer (score 5):

have you installed PyNaCl?
If you don't, download PyNaCl from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/)
Or Install the [Voice Version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) of discord.py
Or and type this to your console

> python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]

and a small Note : Discord.py is now version 1.5.1 (I Don't know if you're up to date) and PyNaCl is now version >1.4.0

Comment: i did install pynacl

Comment: @NishitaTejwani That means, download the [Voice Version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) of discord.py `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]`

Comment: i did install everything

Comment: @NishitaTejwani try typing `pip list` and look for `PyNaCl`, or Tyr to run the console as a admin then try to install it again.

Comment: i have the same issue, everything was working fine until a few weeks ago when it suddenly told me i dont have pynacl, like the other guy i do have it installed.

Comment: @FlyingThunder did you install NodeJs / NPM?

Comment: no, i fixed it by replaying discord.py==1.4.1 in my requirements with discord.py[voice]==1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [PyNaCl](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/) for this to work! You can try `pip install PyNaCl` or `pip3 install PyNaCl` in the terminal,
or you can try pasting the below snippet at the top of you code:

```py
import os
try:
    import nacl
except ImportError:
    try:
        if os.name == 'nt':
            os.system("py -m pip install pynacl")
        else:
            os.system("python3 -m install pynacl")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        exit()
```

This code will download it if it is missing!