# Getting discord bot to join vc but is missing " PyNaCl"

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to get my discord bot to connect to a voice channel but I get the "RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice" error.

This is my code:

```
def __init__(self,client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Voice Lines is online')


@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await ctx.send("trying to connect to ")
        await channel.connect()

    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
    return
```

def setup(client):
client.add_cog(SetVoiceLines(client))

The Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vargh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Dev\DiscordBots\GGBot\cogs\setVoiceLines.py", line 19, in play
    await channel.connect()
  File "C:\Users\vargh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1277, in connect
    voice = cls(client, self)
  File "C:\Users\vargh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 199, in __init__   
    raise RuntimeError("PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice")
RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

And here is the PyNaCL in my python list when I do python list.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0GwU.png)

Comment: Do you have the [Voice Version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) of discord.py? `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]`

Comment: YES thank you! It said requirement satisfied but started download some packages. It now joins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63859231/runtimeerror-pynacl-library-needed-in-order-to-use-voice)